# Iterating through file in Bash and running command

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of .sra files I want to convert into .fastq format using fastq-dump from SRAtools. They're all stored in the same directory, so I'd quite like to run a bash script to just cycle through them all and apply fastq-dump function with the various methods. However, I can't quite get the syntax right.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/sam/Documents/Reads
for file in FILES
do
[ fastq-dump "$file" ]
done
```

This throws 'Unary operator expected'. I'm sure its fairly simple but I'm a bit of a beginner in Bash scripting and not quite sure how the syntax works.

Could anyone give me a hint as to the correct syntax?

Comment: The brackets `[ ]` are shell syntax for tests, their return value (0 for true, non-zero for false) is intended to be used as a logical value, and they are typically used to build `if/then/else` blocks, loop termination conditions, or conditional execution with `&&` and `||` logical operators.  When you just want to execute a command, you do not enclose it in brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the square brackets. And change `FILES` to `"$FILES"/*` so the variable value is expanded and the files in that directory are matched.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/sam/Documents/Reads
for file in "$FILES"/*
do
    fastq-dump "$file"
done
```

The loop isn't really necessary, actually. `fastq-dump` can take multiple file names. You could write simply:

```
fastq-dump /home/sam/Documents/Reads/*
```

Comment: Ah OK - the first way worked - think it would be better to learn how to use a loop in bash anyway. Thanks!